# In React, how can I save and display a search term as it's being typed while updating search results on each character typed?

Tags: reactjs

Sorry if the question title isn't so clear, I wasn't sure how best to word my problem.

So I've made a search bar in React that searches through an array of objects (movies) and returns matching results. My problem is that when I type the first character and it filters and returns already with data matching that character (as intended), it does not keep the character just typed in and the search bar is just an empty input box again.

So for example, if I'm trying to search for 'Casablanca', I start by typing 'c', it will return all movies with 'c' in their title, it does not save the 'c' though, so if I try to continue typing 'Casablanca' and enter 'a', it's returning all movies with just 'a' in their title, rather than 'ca'.

Here's my code:

```
const Index = (props) => {
    const [ movies, setMovies ] = useState(null);
    const [ filter, setFilter ] = React.useState("");

    function SearchBar({ onSearch }) {
        const onSub = (e) => {
            onSearch(e.target.value.toLowerCase());
        };
      
        return (
            <form>
                <div>
                    <input
                        onChange={onSub}
                        className="search-input"
                        placeholder="Search"
                        name="search"
                    />
                </div>
            </form>
        );
    }


    function SearchPage() {
        const filteredData = React.useMemo(() => { 
            if (filter === "") return movies;
            return movies.filter((item) =>
                item.primaryTitle.toLowerCase().includes(filter)
            );
        }, []);
        
        const moviesList = filteredData.map((movie) => {
            return  <Grid xs={6} md={4}> 
                        <MovieCard 
                            key={movie._id} 
                            movie={movie} 
                            authenticated={props.authenticated} 
                        /> 
                    </Grid>;
        });

        return (
            <>
                <SearchBar onSearch={(searchTerm) => setFilter(searchTerm)}/>
                <h2>Movies</h2>
                <Grid container spacing={2}>
                { moviesList }
                </Grid>
            </>
        );
    }

    return (
        <>
            <SearchPage />
        </>
    );
};

export default Index;
```

So the issue is around the SearchBar() and it's input, but I've included some other things in case it's helpful/relevant.

I tried to set a variable in a couple of different ways that would store and update the search term as it's being typed, and then use that variable as the input's placeholder text, like this:

```
function SearchBar({ onSearch }) {
        let testing = "";

        const onSub = (e) => {
            onSearch(e.target.value.toLowerCase());
            testing = testing + e.target.value;
            console.log("testing = " + testing)
        };
      
        return (
            <form>
                <div>
                    <input
                        onChange={onSub}
                        className="search-input"
                        placeholder="Search"
                        name="search"
                        value={testing}
                    />
                </div>
            </form>
        );
    }
```

But it didn't work, the specific example above did not concatenate the strings, just overrode the string that was already there. It also  never even updated the placeholder text of the input.

Does anyone know how I can go about solving this? I appreciate any help, and please let me know if there's any more information I can provide that could be useful, thank you.

Comment: You are not saving the input state. I've made a simple example in codesandbox. It's made with Typescript but I think is pretty self explanatory: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-noyce-xl70ur?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've been testing around with your code example and trying to integrate it with my code, I'm very unfamiliar with Typescript though. I've managed to get the search box keeping the entered characters, but every time it returns with the filtered data it takes the focus away from the search box, so you have to click inside the search box again to continue typing a word/term. Do you know is this just because of the returning data, or because I haven't been able to use your code exactly as formatted?

Comment: I think its a rerender problem caused by setFilter. It would be great if you could upload a demo of your code to codesandbox

Comment: I've never put anything in codesandbox before, but I gave it a go. It works, but you gotta comment out '<SearchPage />' on line 76 of App.js, and then uncomment it again and it works and shows my problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-bird-cejyof?file=/src/App.js:1743-1757

Comment: It's a rerender problem. You need to move the SearchBar component outside the App component. What is happening here is that every time the state in App change it's rendering the App component, so it will render your SearchBar component.